# Laravel 5.6 Date of Birth Validation

Tags: php, laravel

I created validation rules in my Member Model with date of birth NOT being required. However, when someone does fill in their date of birth, I want it to be 
1. in the correct format and 
2. the date cannot be a date in the future.

However, when I fill out my form and leave date of birth empty, I still get the following error:

[image]

Here my basic Member.php model:

```
use Esensi\Model\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|alpha|min:2|max:255',
        'surname' => 'required|alpha|min:2|max:255',
        'id_number' => 'required|unique:members,id_number|digits:13',
        'mobile_number' => 'required|digits:10',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'date_of_birth' => 'date_format:Y-M-D|before:today',
    ];
}
```

Here's my MemberController.php store function:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $member = new Member;
    $member->name = $request->name;
    $member->surname = $request->surname;
    $member->id_number = $request->id_number;
    $member->mobile_number = $request->mobile_number;
    $member->email = $request->email;
    $member->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;

    if(!$member->save()){
        $errors = $member->getErrors();

         return redirect()
            ->action('MemberController@create')
            ->with('errors', $errors)
            ->withInput();
}
//successful creation
    return redirect()
        ->action('MemberController@index')
        ->with('message', '<div class="alert alert-success">Member Created Successfully!</div>');

}
```

How do I fix it so that date of birth only shows an error when the field is actually filled in but the formatting is incorrect?

Comment: try `'date_of_birth' => 'date_format:Y-M-D|before:today|nullable',`

Comment: @jproux try 'y-m-d' instead of 'Y-M-D'

Answer (score 7):

Here you will find the `date` rules for different conditions:

```
$v = Validator::make(
  ['start_date' => date('30-05-2028')], // input
  [
    'date_of_birth' => ['before:5 years ago'],
    'start_date'    => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y|after:8 years',
    'end_date'      => 'date_format:d-m-Y|after:start_date', 
    ]
);

if ($v->passes())
 dd('Your Date format is correct.');
else
 dd($v->errors());
```

For your case you should try:

```
'date_of_birth' => 'date_format:Y-m-d|before:today|nullable'
```

Careful: You must use this `Y-m-d` format. Not this `Y-M-D`.
Month and Date parameter must be in lower case. Hope it will solve your issues.

Answer (score 4):

```
'date_of_birth' => 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-d|before:today',
```

Answer (score 1):

i think an easier approach would be

```
'date_of_birth' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|before:'.now()->subYears(18)->toDateString()
```

assuming valid age is 18 years

Comment: Nowehere in the question does it mention a requirement to have a "valid age."

Comment: Thats why i said assuming valid age is 18, in case someone wondered why i subtracted 18 years..

Answer (score 0):

Just an extra thought...

I added nullable to date_of_birth and then got a SQL error stating that date_of_birth is not allowed to be null. I forgot to set the column to allow nulls in my schema

Thanks, the suggestions helped